# Linq to filter nested list

Tags: c#, linq

Ok, I wrote below `LINQ to Entities` query (close enough to my c# query showing below)

```
var itemss = filteredstudents
.Where(x => x.SubjectTypes.Any(y => y.SubjectItem.Any(z => z.Name  == value1))).ToList();
```

still little problem because when SubjectItem type has two element and one of them match with `value1`. it still returns both. It should return only matching record. I know the problem is with Any but not sure `Any` to replace with what?

```
foreach (StudentDTO student in filteredstudents)
{
    bool valid = true;
    foreach (SubjectTypes subjectType in student.SubjectTypes)
    {
        string value1 = subjectType.SubjectItem.Select(x => x.value1).First();
        Guid StId = _context.Items.Where(x => x.Name == value1).FirstOrDefault();

        if (StId != null)
            valid = true;
        else
        {
            valid = false;
            _log("create log");
        }
    }
    if (valid)
        filteredstudentsWithUnits.Add(student);
}
```

**Sample Input**

```
{"Name":"ABC",
"Age":12,
,"SubjectTypes":
[
{"Id":"1","Description":""Description","SubjectItem":[{"Id":"1","Marks":12,"Name":"aaa"}]},
{"Id":"1","Description":""Description","SubjectItem":[{"Id":"1","Marks":12,"Name":"aaa"}]},
{"Id":"1","Description":""Description","SubjectItem":[{"Id":"1","Marks":12,"Name":"bbb"}]}
]
}
```

**Expected Output**

```
{"Name":"ABC",
"Age":12,
,"SubjectTypes":
[
{"Id":"1","Description":""Description","SubjectItem":[{"Id":"1","Marks":12,"Name":"aaa"}]},
{"Id":"1","Description":""Description","SubjectItem":[{"Id":"1","Marks":12,"Name":"aaa"}]},

]
}
```

Comment: please share the relationship between `SubjectTypes` and `SubjectItem`

Comment: Also it will be helpful if you post example data and expected output

Comment: Can you explain what should happen in the case of multiple items? Should it only return if there is one item and it matches and if so what it the problem you are having with doing that (seems no harder than other stuff you're up to here)

Comment: It should just return / filter only matching data.

Comment: @ Gilad Green, I have updated my question with sample input and expected output data. Its json format.

Comment: `filteredstudents.SubjectTypes.Where(y => y.SubjectItem.Any(z => z.Name  == value1))` would do the filtering you want.  Then just add that list to a new shallow copy (or new instance) of the parent type.

Comment: It's unclear what is `StudentDTO` and how do you populate it. If it's an entity type, then you are using lazy loading and what you get is the expected behavior. If it's not, it would be good to show how do you populate it from entity.

Comment: @stephen.vakil filteredstudents is also collection.list. Thats why i used filteredstudents.where......

Comment: May be i am not able to well explain but can't me sample data and expected output tells the whole story what i am looking for !!!

Comment: @simbada use the where condition in your `foreach` loop and then set the value of `SubjectTypes` to the resulting list.

Comment: @stephen.vakil sorry didn't get your point.. can you write sample of what you mean to make it more clear to me to understand? in my c# query which i originally wrote, i used foreach .... but that what i wanted to replace with proper LINQ to Entities.  can you write your sample clearly?

Answer (score 4):

You could filter the list first using `.Where` and then use `.Select` to project to a new collection that contains only the data you want. Something like the following may work:

```
var itemss = filteredstudents
    .Where(s => s.SubjectTypes.Any(st => st.SubjectItem.Any(si => si.Name  == value1)))
    .Select(s => new StudentDTO
    {
        Name = s.Name,
        Age = s.Age,
        SubjectTypes = s.SubjectTypes.Where(st => st.SubjectItem.Any(si => si.Name  == value1))
            .Select(st => new SubjectType
            {
                Id = st.Id,
                Description = st.Description,
                SubjectItem = st.SubjectItem.Where(si => si.Name == value1).ToList()
            }).ToList()
    })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

This will solve your issue but there may be better ways of doing it, also I omitted some properties like the Ids and marks that you'll need to add.

```
var items = filteredstudents.Select(s => new StudentDTO
{
    Name = s.Name,
    SubjectTypes = s.SubjectTypes.Select(st => new SubjectType
    {
        Description = st.Description,
        SubjectItems = st.SubjectItems.Where(si => si.Name == "AAA").ToList()
    }).Where(x => x.SubjectItems.Count > 0).ToList()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The below logic might help you to filter only nested list.

For ex:

Consider below class structure:

```
class EntityName { int i; string xx; List<SubEntity> subEntityName; }
```

Then, filter only the `subEntity` details like this.

```
objEntity.SubEntityName = objEntity.SubEntityName.Where(x=>x.attrubute== "")"
```